# Can't override taken photo with same URI

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, uri

This is the weirdest behaviour I have faced from android so far.

I want to take a photo and crop it afterwards. This is the relevant code:

```
private void manageTakePhotoClicked() {
    outputFileUri = prepareNewFileUri();
    if(outputFileUri == null){
        Toast.makeText(ProfilePicture.this, "Unable to prepare directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_FROM_PHOTO_TAKEN);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ProfilePicture.this, "No camera found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}

private Uri prepareNewFileUri(){
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + FOLDER);
        if (directory.isDirectory() || directory.mkdirs()) {
            File file = new File(directory, "avatar.jpg");
            return Uri.fromFile(file);
        } else {
            Log.d("foo", "Couldn't create directions");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("foo", "not mounted ");
    }
    return null;
}
```

In OnActivityResult, I just trigger the image cropping:

```
private void startCropActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setDataAndType(outputFileUri, "image/*");
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", THUMBNAIL_SIZE_WIDTH);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", THUMBNAIL_SIZE_HEIGHT);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", THUMBNAIL_SIZE_WIDTH);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", THUMBNAIL_SIZE_HEIGHT);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, FROM_CROP);
}
```

This works only the first time. The next time I take a picture and want to crop it, the first picture is taken for cropping. If I take a look in this folder from a file manager, I can see the correct thumbnail from the latest taken photo. If I click on it, it takes about 5-8 seconds to open the photo, it shows the first photo taken and if I zoom in or out, it switches to the second picture taken (on the fly) but not further. summed up: I take 5 pictures, I cancel the crop process, I see the latest picture in the thumbnail, the first picture by default and the second picture when I pinchzoom.

One more thing: I can delete the whole folder and still get the same effect.

btw: everything works fine when I use unique names for the prepared file. But thats not what I want.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Look what you have:

```
intent.setDataAndType(outputFileUri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
```

You can't set the **outputFileUri** over the **inputFileUri**, otherwise you are going to have one image overlapped with others like you are experiencing.

*You can do this, for example:*

Use the following methods,

```
private void setUriTemp(Uri uri) {
    getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("key_uri_temp", uri.toString())
            .commit();
}

private Uri getUriTemp() {
    String filePath = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("key_uri_temp", null);
    return Uri.parse(filePath);
}

private File getTempFile() {
    File tempFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), ".temp");
    try {
        tempFile.createNewFile();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return tempFile;
}
```

then change your's like this:

```
private void manageTakePhotoClicked() {
    outputFileUri = getTempFile();
    if (outputFileUri == null) {
        Toast.makeText(ProfilePicture.this, "Unable to prepare directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    } else {
        setUriTemp(outputFileUri);
        try {
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_FROM_PHOTO_TAKEN);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(ProfilePicture.this, "No camera found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }
}

private void startCropActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setDataAndType(getUriTemp(), "image/*");
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", THUMBNAIL_SIZE_WIDTH);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", THUMBNAIL_SIZE_HEIGHT);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", THUMBNAIL_SIZE_WIDTH);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", THUMBNAIL_SIZE_HEIGHT);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, prepareNewFileUri());
    startActivityForResult(intent, FROM_CROP);
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Still the same problem. If at any point in time, I created a file "x.jpg", no matter what I do in the future, x.jpg ALWAYS stays the same picture. I even can delete the file, or better: uninstall the whole app and reinstall it. file.delete does not change anything either. I am very confused